# Why am I starting to see bubbles after painting a wall?

Tags: walls, painting

One section of the wall isn't exactly as smooth as the rest. It has bubbles of paint forming on it that can be rubbed off. They very tiny. The walls aren't dry wall and the section that is I'm question used to be a window.

I didn't do it myself. But what I know is, remodelling old painted walls. It was prepared and painted two coats of new paint. The unique part of this section is it was a window or opening for old AC unit. The old paint showed clear cracks around the frames of old "window" showing that previous painters were unable to repair the wall.

Now I'm facing something similar maybe with the tiny bubbles. I asked around and people dismissed it as a problem, said it's just cosmetic feature.

[image]

Comment: Please *edit* to add detail. It doesn't belong in a comment.

Comment: *"The walls aren't dry wall"* ... so what *are* they?

Comment: Like concrete, or brick. It's the same wall as the exterior, so load bearing wall is what it's called?

Answer (score 1):

If it's concrete or plaster applied to brick, that's a porous surface, which can lead to bubbles like this if not sealed/primed beforehand. At this stage, you could treat the paint itself as your (rather expensive) primer coat. Basically the wall has now been sealed with paint instead of primer, so you can sand it smooth and paint a final coat on top. As long as you don't fall prey to [the other things that can cause bubbles](https://www.sherwin-williams.com/home-builders/products/resources/SW-ARTICLE-PRO-BUBBLINGFOAMING) (all user error, not product issues) then you should have a smooth finish.

Those you asked are likely correct that this is nothing more than a cosmetic issue. Other more serious concerns (excess moisture, etc.), would likely manifest in a more obvious way than just tiny bubbles in paint.

Comment: Could it be not big of a deal? Could I leave it and the paint will set in to not give me any trouble in the future?  It might not be easy to get someone  to redo it and I might mess it up. Primer was used on older paint, and it seemed confidently done up until I saw the bubbles. They can be rubbed off or sanded off I guess.

Comment: Unless it's in a really humid environment, like a bathroom, where moisture could get between the paint layers and enlarge these bubbles, I really wouldn't worry about it at all.

Comment: Not a bathroom, next to window and exposed to a breeze. I could rub the bubbles off with my fingers. I don't want to bring someone to redo it unnecessarily, they might think I'm too obsessive too since there is no clear cracks or big bubbles yet which is what people take seriously.